# In-line block elements and positioning/alignment

Tags: html, alignment, css

This is the misaligned output of the code below.

[image]

```
.recipes-mobile-menu {
    display:block;
    width:350px;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
}

.recipes-mobile-menu a:link, .recipes-mobile-menu a:visited, .recipes-mobile-menu a:active {
    display:inline-block;
    background: #002b76;
    width:19%;
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:0.85em;
    padding:10px 4px;
    margin:0;
    white-space:normal;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}

.recipes-mobile-menu a:hover, .recipes-mobile-menu a.on {
    background:#da2b28; 
}



<div class="recipes-mobile-menu">
    <a href="/recipes/extra-kick-eats">Extra<br>kick<br>Eats</a>
    <a href="/recipes/louisiana-recipes">Louisiana<br>Recipes</a>
    <a href="/recipes/family-favorites">Family<br>Favorites</a>
    <a href="/recipes/asian-recipes" class="on">Asian<br>recipes</a>
    <a href="/recipes/winning-wing-recipes">Winning<br>Wing<br>Recipes</a>
</div>
```

This fiddle also shows the misalignment.   http://jsfiddle.net/muzfuq7t/

My confusion is coming from fact that the vertical alignment seems to change only if I use developer console to change length of text inside the links.

Changing width, height, padding, and margin does not correct the vertical alignment.

What is happening there and how do I correct it?

Comment: `vertical-align: top;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `vertical-align` is for :)

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Add this to your `inline-block` elements!

Comment: Thank you.  Will accept as soon as SO lets me.  Still seems like a wonky way for a browser to render what was there.

Comment: If you look at the text, the bottom line seems to be continually aligned; and this is how we'd like it if suddenly a short span of letters were bigger (like the first letter of a chapter in a novel). However, on this occasion you want your "letters" to be aligned by their top.

Comment: I figured out that the unexpected behaviour is caused by the number of lines inside each block, for example if every one of them has 2 lines, they align just fine, and every box that has 3 lines goes "up", or pushes the rest down by a line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`vertical-align:top;`** to align vertically inline-block elements.

or alternatively you could also use **`float:left;`** and add **`margin:2px;`**.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/muzfuq7t/4/